# OpenCart: 2Checout Logged users gets logged out on success page

Tags: opencart

I have 2checkout return customers to the URL
http://store.com/index.php?route=checkout/success. Which is correct? Anyway, 2checkout sent me to the homepage after successful payment and showing as a visitor with empty cart., when click on continue button showing logged in and same cart items in cart.and

opencart didn't record the order nor did i receive any order confirmation via email.(Required)

The customer received an order confirmation but product's option (if any) is not shown. Please help!!

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Could you please rewrite your question so that it is more clear? Now it looks to me little bit messy. Please use simple (short) sentences only. Describe the current behavior in one paragraph and the desired one in another so that it does not mess together (i.e. now I do not know which is the correct and incorrect one).

Comment: login problem solved...
i mention required for required task. @shadyyx